# When is an "if-none-match"-request sent?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-caching, etag, if-none-match

While optimizing the caching-behaviour of our website, I noticed that a whole lot of `if-none-match`-requests are sent to our site. As far as I understand caching, this should not be the case as long as the cache is still valid.

One particular request generates the following `response-header`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=25920000
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Thu, 04 Feb 2016 17:20:09 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 01 Jan 2001 23:00:00 GMT
ETag: W/"0"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 16:20:09 GMT
```

As you can see, the cache should be valid for 300 days. The way I understand it,  the browser should use its cache directly during that period. Only after this period is over, it should issue a request with the header `if-none-match`.
But browsers seem to ignore that and send this `if-none-match` -request each and every time the page is loaded just to receive a `304-response ("Not Modified")`.

What do I need to change to keep browsers from sending these useless requests?

Comment: No idea, but wouldn't replacing the HTTP/1.0 tags by `Cache-Control: max-age=600`? help?

Comment: Can you tell approximately how many such requests you see? Might it be from clients reloading the page? This might trigger some browsers to revalidate the resources.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, while the cache is fresh browsers should use a local copy without revalidation. However, this is not guaranteed. For example, when users use the [Refresh button](https://bitsup.blogspot.co.uk/2016/05/cache-control-immutable.html) browsers make requests to the origin server anyway.

There is a [`Cache-Control: immutable, max-age=…`](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/01/using-immutable-caching-to-speed-up-the-web/) extension that tells browsers you really really mean they should use the cached resource without contacting the server.